# how do I get the library curses.h?

Tags: curses, conio

I'm trying to compile a project someone wrote in `visual C` on my `Netbeans+cygwin`, and there are a lot of libraries I don't have.

One of the problems is `conio.h`, and it seems like I can use `curses.h`.
How do I get curses library?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Use the Cygwin package manager.

Comment: @SevenBits Windows 7! i managed to get it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Cygwin, as larsmans suggested.